# Run Time Error 1004 Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to parse multiple documents within a folder and copy the whole matching rows to the open spreadsheet.
I have seen on the microsoft website that this could be part of a known issue and saving inside the code could resolve the issue. However I am stumped on how to do so.
Strangely the macro will work on all of the files in the defined folder on their own just not together. 
The part of the code that is causing issue is bold.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Steve

```
 Dim myDir As String, fn As String, ws As Worksheet, r As Range
    Dim a(), n As Long, x As Long, myTask As String, ff As String, temp
    myDir = "C:\Users\stacys.CAMKMG-BLR\Desktop\MyFolder\" '<- change path to folder with files to search
    If Dir(myDir, 16) = "" Then
        MsgBox "No such folder path", 64, myDir
        Exit Sub
    End If
    myTask = InputBox("Enter Policy Type")
    If myTask = "" Then Exit Sub
    x = Columns.Count
    fn = Dir(myDir & "*.xls*")
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    Do While fn <> ""
        With Workbooks.Open(myDir & fn, 0)
            For Each ws In .Worksheets
                Set r = ws.Cells.Find(myTask, , , 1)
                If Not r Is Nothing Then
                    ff = r.Address
                    Do
                        n = n + 1
                        temp = r.EntireRow.Value
                        ReDim Preserve temp(1 To 1, 1 To x)
                        ReDim Preserve a(1 To n)
                        a(n) = temp
                        Set r = ws.Cells.FindNext(r)
                    Loop While ff <> r.Address
                End If
            Next
            .Close False
        End With
        fn = Dir
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(1)
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        If n > 0 Then
            **.Resize(n).Value = _
            Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(a))**
        Else
            MsgBox "Not found", , myTask
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is causing the issue? Can't see any bit in Bold

Comment: There is no "Bold" in code formatted text. Could you tell exactly where is the problem?

Comment: Oh... Ill update. but its this line      .Resize(n).Value = _
            Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(a))

Comment: Can you try changing `.Rows(1)` to `.Cells(1)` in your `With` block

Comment: Thanks Tom. However same issue sadly

Comment: I noted from this article that it may be a known issue, but am unsure of how to apply the extra saving
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/210684/copying-worksheet-programmatically-causes-run-time-error-1004-in-excel

Comment: I created several test files with a few variations of potential problems but the code seems to work every time for me.  What is the `n` value when it throws an error?  I only get that error if I manually make `n` negative but you're already checking for that condition.

Comment: n is currently 1811. Maybe its too large? Thanks for looking, I am stumped